# Python modules for wrapper functions

Tags: python

I am trying to write a generic module that provides functions that act as a wrapper to specific implementation.
Example, my main.py script will call profile.py functions `profile()`.  The profile.py will then call either machineA or machineB `measure()` function depending on the cmd line arg which i pass in.

```
/main.py

    tools/profile.py  -- # provides function profile

          machineA/measure.py  # provides function measure

          machineB/measure.py # provides function measure
```

Currently my tools/profile.py does this

```
if machine == 'machineA':
  from machineA import measure
else:
  from machineB import measure

def profile():
  return measure.measure()
```

I am using modules to do this functionality,  I think there maybe a way to do this with classes, however i am not too familiar with classes to know how to get started. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: If this is working for you, I think it's fine. If there's something about it you don't like, tell us.

Comment: The only thing a class would do here, really, is add an extra layer of indirection around your access to `measure`. In some sense, a module *is* a class, but one that is, and can be, instantiated only once.

Comment: I did end up using a class in profile.py and the __init__() i import the correct module. Its working fine, I thought there maybe a cleaner Object oriented way to have the machineA and machineB be a child class and inherit from the profile.py as abstract class. That way I can create an instance of abstract profile.py class.

Answer (score 0):

The simple (though hacky) way is to use `__import__` directly.

```
measure = __import__(machine).measure
```

Slightly cleaner would be to use the `importlib` module.

```
import importlib
measure = importlib.import_module(machine).measure
```

Comment: Yep thats what I ended up doing. I wanted to actually see if there was a way to use OOP to define a generic Abstract class in profile.py and have the machineA and machineB be child class and implement the methods. Then I would create an instance of the abstract class in the main.py and instantiate based on the machineA or machineB.